# Setting up aliases with interactive ssh session

Tags: shell, ssh, login, remote, profile

I need to keep ssh'ing into *many-different* Linux boxes (Ubuntu mostly) and every time I miss my basic aliases. Is there a way to setup aliases etc

- while opening an interactive `ssh` a machine
- without tinkering with remote machines's `.bashrc/.bash_profile`?

Following would just execute the alias commands in a non-interactive shell on remote machine and terminate the session (as expected):
`kashyap@Laptop$ ssh root@ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-6.amazonaws.com "alias c=clear; alias p=pwd; alias l='ls -altr'`

I would love it if I could select a file from local machine to be executed as init script on remote, but willing to settle for less.

E.g.

```
ssh usr@remote --init-script=/local/my_init_script_for_ssh_sessions
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by adding

`LocalCommand scp username@yourserver:~/.bashrc /serverhome/.bashrc;source .bashrc`

line to your ssh config file. There is also a `PermitLocalCommand` option that needs to be set to true.

Comment: `LocalCommand` doesn't have access to the session and is run locally.

Comment: Thats the idea it will scp file and source bashrc on session initiate

Comment: It is going to execute **locally**, on the machine where you run `ssh`, not on the machine where you run `sshd`. Try using `hostname` as your `LocalCommand` and see on which host in executes.

Comment: This can work partially if You have the host configured in .ssh/config and replace the username with %r, yourserver with %h. But then the source .bashrc won't reload the before created session.